# Type of Cypress testIsolation property

Tags: typescript, cypress

There is a property called **testIsolation** that was introduced in Cypress 12. Im currently upgrading from 11 to 13.
The property is apparently a string:

```
(property) testIsolation?: "on" | "off" | null | undefined
```

but i get a typescript error when i use 'on'

```
cypress.config.ts(72,9): error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'.
```

So is it a **boolean or string**?
In the Cypress documentation it looks like its a boolean
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation
but that is not accepted.

Do I need to communicate the cypress types to typescript somehow?

Comment: Stuff like this is quite often because of multi-package dependencies. Does your project require any `@cypress/*` package? Have they been updated? Another angle: when you run `npm list cypress` (or `yarn why cypress` for yarn, `pnpm why cypress` for pnpm) do you get only one instance of the dep, with one consistent version? Accidental multiple versions is a common issue here. Finally, if this error is in your IDE, make sure to restart it, it may be holding the old types in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The Cypress team changed the type from string to boolean in Cypress 12.